# Update UIImageView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2, setneedsdisplay

Newbie programmer here.  I'm trying to simulate the interaction of homes within a village.

I have a function (A) below that draws a simulated village (each rectangle stands for a house in the village).  The issue I have is that I have another function (B - not shown except for small part below) (kicked off by a button press) that changes the underlying array that drives how the village looks.  It does so in a for loop.  So within function B, I run 100 iterations, and at each iteration, I call function (A) to redraw the village.  The problem is that the app only draws the village at the end of the 100th loop.  I've tried setNeedsDisplay, etc, with no luck, and I'd like to see the village drawn at each iteration so that it creates a bit of animation as rectangles will change from iter to iter.

Excerpt from Function B...

```
for iIter... 100 times {
   drawVillage()
   imageView.setNeedsDisplay() <-- TRYING TO REFRESH HERE
}
```

Function A...

```
func drawVillage() {

    let xSize: Int = Int (gxRes / gxHomes); let ySize: Int = Int (gyRes / gyHomes)
    let xRes = Int(gxHomes * xSize); let yRes = Int(gyHomes * ySize)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: xRes, height: yRes), false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var iStatus: Int

    for var yHome: Int = 1; yHome <= gyHomes; ++yHome {
        for var xHome: Int = 1; xHome <= gxHomes; ++xHome {

            var rectangle = CGRect(x: (xHome - 1) * xSize, y: (yHome - 1) * ySize, width: xSize, height: ySize)

            iStatus = gaVillageStatus[xHome][yHome]
            if iStatus == 0 {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
            } else if iStatus == 1 {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor)
            } else if iStatus == 2 {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
            } else if iStatus == 3 {
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
            }

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)

            CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
            CGContextDrawPath(context, .FillStroke)

        }
    }

    var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageView.image = img

}
```

Comment: Still haven't found a solution - anyone to help please?  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post to hopefully make it easier to follow.  Please someone help!

Comment: UIView.setNeedsDisplay just notifies the system that your view should be redrawn. It doesn't redraw it at that time but during the next update cycle. I guess your loop completes and then iOS redraws your view having lumped all setNeedDisplay requests together. I guess you'll want to something like [UIView animateWithDuration:]

Comment: Thanks - I guess, coming from a Visual Basic world, I'm struggling with threads, etc.  In Visual Basic, if I tell the program to draw something, and then I call that function, it redraws.  Isn't there a way to just force a redraw whenever I'd like the app to do so?